# Xamarin forms eventToCommand behavior for zxing library

Tags: xamarin

i'm trying to use the event to command behavior for the zxing barcode scanning.

```
var eventParameters = eventinfo.EventHandlerType
                .GetRuntimeMethods().First(m => m.Name == "Invoke")
                .GetParameters()
                .Select(p => Expression.Parameter(p.ParameterType))
                .ToArray();

            var actionInvoke = action.GetType()
                .GetRuntimeMethods().First(m => m.Name == "Invoke");

                _handler = Expression.Lambda(
                eventinfo.EventHandlerType,
                Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(action), actionInvoke, eventParameters[0], eventParameters[1]),
                eventParameters).Compile();

            eventinfo.AddEventHandler(item, _handler);
```

this code works fine for any other event that has (object sender and event args) but the zxing event has only one argument. Do u know how can i make this code to work?

Answer (score 0):

The EventToCommandBehavior will probably pass arguments as object type.

Add this the your eventToCommandBehavior

```
public static BindableProperty EventArgsConverterProperty = BindableProperty.CreateAttached("EventArgsConverter", typeof(IValueConverter), typeof(EventToCommandBehavior), null, BindingMode.OneWay);

...

public IValueConverter EventArgsConverter
{
   get { return (IValueConverter)GetValue(EventArgsConverterProperty); }
   set { SetValue(EventArgsConverterProperty, value); }
}

...
```

This is the implementation of YourEventArgsConverter.

```
public class YourEventArgsConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Converter(object value, Type, targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {

      var eventArgs = value as [PUT YOUR EVENT ARGS TYPE HERE];
      if (eventArgs == null) 
         throw new ArgumentException("Expected YOUR EVENT ARGS TYPE as value", value)

      return eventArgs;
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type, targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new NoImplementedException();
   }
}
```

You can use the EventArgsConvert like this.

```
...
<ResourceDictionary>
   <converters:YourEventArgsConverter x:Key="YourEventArgsConverter" />
</ResourceDictionary>
...

<behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior
   EventName="YOUREVENTNAME"
   EventArgsConverter="{StaticResource YourEventArgsConverter}"
   Command="{Binding EventCommand}" />
...
```